# Is there a way to run static scope for every subclass once?

Tags: java, static

I have the next class :

```
public abstract class base {
   public static String name = "baseClass";
   static {
         System.out.println(name)
   }
}
```

I that this code will run in every method which `extends` this class and that it will happend after the c'tor of the subclass.

for Example for:

```
public subclass extends base {
   @Override
   public static String name = "subclassInfo";

   public subclass(){
      System.out.println("hello")
   }
}
```

I want to get in the first run: 
**hello**
**subclassInfo**

and in the next run I'll get only **hello**

I didn't want to move the static scope to the subclass, I want it will something that move from the base to the subclass and happened only in the first call of the subclass

Comment: What do you think about AOP? It may be helpful for you.

Comment: @DariaPydorenko how would you implement it in AOP?

Comment: `static` + `this` are contradictory. There is no `this` in a `static` context.

Comment: @Andreas I change it, but this is not the main question, I'll be happy if you could change your vote to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the subclass name the first time an instance of the subclass is created, do this:

```java
public abstract class Base {
    private static final Map<Class<?>, Boolean> subclasses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    {
        if (subclasses.putIfAbsent(this.getClass(), Boolean.TRUE) == null)
            System.out.println("New subclass: " + this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
class Sub1 extends Base {
}
class Sub2 extends Base {
}
class Sub3 extends Base {
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Sub3());
        System.out.println(new Sub1());
        System.out.println(new Sub1());
        System.out.println(new Sub3());
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
New subclass: Sub3
Sub3@24d46ca6
New subclass: Sub1
Sub1@372f7a8d
Sub1@2f92e0f4
Sub3@28a418fc
```

Comment: This is probably as close to what OP wants as possible. There is no mechanism to  automagically notify a class if a subclass of itself gets loaded.